# Create a file in ApplicationScripts directory in a sandboxed macOS app

Tags: swift, macos, security, sandbox, bookmarks

I want to create a (".scpt") file inside the macOS apps' application scripts directory.

When starting the app for the 1st time I'm presenting a `NSOpenPanel` to obtain a security scoped bookmark for the app scripts dir that is stored to disk.

```
let data = try url.bookmarkData(options: .withSecurityScope, includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil, relativeTo: nil)
... // store to disk
```

The retrieval ...

```
var bookmark: Bookmark = ... // load from storage
var isStale = false
let url = try! URL.init(resolvingBookmarkData: bookmark.value, options: .withSecurityScope, relativeTo: nil, bookmarkDataIsStale: &isStale
```

... and usage of the bookmarks seems to work: `url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()`returns `true`

But creation of file inside that directory fails:

```
let bundleUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "foo", withExtension: "scpt")!
try! FileManager.default.copyItem(at: bundleUrl, to: url.appendingPathComponent("copyOfFoo.scpt"))
```

Exception:

`Operation not permitted`

> Failed to create copyOfFoo.scpt ... couldn’t be copied because you don’t have permission to access “com...

Any hint? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you have under Targets > Capabilities > App Sandbox > File Access?

Comment: I set `User selected file` to `read/write`

Answer (score 0):

After toggling **App Sandbox** feature off and on again it started to work as expected.